# Parent's state is not passed to Child properly

Tags: reactjs, state, lifecycle

Could I ask a very simple question, why App state is not passed to props of Child1? 
From following code, Child1 component should show isLoggedIn of App in the p tag, however it does not show it. Could you give some advice for it?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Child1 from "./Child1";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loginId = setInterval(() => {
      var loggedIn = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? true : false;
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: loggedIn });
      console.log(this.state.isLoggedIn, "isLoggedIn");
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child1 isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child1.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Child 1 </h1>
        <p>Currently LoggedIn is {this.props.isLoggedIn}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child1;
```

My react version informations are following.

```
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-scripts": "2.1.1"
```

[image]

Comment: Code looks fine. Try to `console.log(this.props)` in child component and post it here.

Comment: It prints out correctly for example, {isLoggedIn: false}. Thank you so much.

Comment: The code is correct. I would expect a bug in your build system (are you checking the current version of the app?) or some import related problem (are you importing from the correct file?).

Comment: I edited question Thank you so much. Could you give some advice? I don't understand it.

Comment: Try adding `{"" + this.props.isLoggedIn}`.

Comment: It is working fine, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

bool can't be presented.
you can just do something like this:

```
    <p>Currently LoggedIn is {this.props.isLoggedIn.toString()}</p>
```